# How should I code the back end of a timeline

Tags: python, qt, data-structures, timeline

I want to create a program with a timeline much like the ones you'd see in a video editor. The events that are placed on that timeline will have a starting time and an ending time (or a length?). It will be possible to move the timeline's playhead freely, forward and backwards, and even control it's speed. What is important is that the playhead should trigger the events when it "enters" or "exits" the objects as it moves over them. I don't want to use timers since there could be quite a lot of those events and it would probably be inefficient.

What would be the best way to view this problem? I've already coded the graphical part (using QGraphicsView where the events are represented using custom QGraphicsItems), now I'm looking for the best way to implement the back end.

Did my question make sense? Is it too ambiguous?

Comment: Do you mean something like the timeline from this project? http://www.openshot.org/screenshots/

Comment: Should the playhead fire events when it "moves over" the timeline elements, or only when it's released? That makes a difference.

Comment: @JonClements Indeed. Actually, right before asking this question, I was browsing through OpenShot's source code. But I didn't get a clear idea of how the timeline was implemented.

Comment: @frb It would be best if an "enter" event was fired as the playhead "entered" the "object" and an "exit" event as it "exited". Backwards or forwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want a data structure that efficiently supports the following operations:

1. Insert and delete time intervals.
2. Shift a time interval over.
3. Query for all time intervals overlapping with a certain time.

For this, you might want to look at the **[interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)** data structure, which efficiently supports operations (1) and (3).  You can implement operation (2) by deleting an existing segment and then reinserting it into the interval tree.

To implement the reading pointer, you can just continuously query the segment tree for all segments overlapping the current time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it may be exactly what I'm looking for. It'll probably take me a little time to go through it all, but from what I understand, it reminds me of the BSP tree which is the data structure used in the QGraphicsScene.

Comment: I'll add this here: http://www.dgp.utoronto.ca/people/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/
It's a practical explanation of the interval tree data structure.